# How can I make coinprice-indicator open from startup?

Tags: 14.04, indicator, startup, bitcoin

I have coinprice-indicator, it is an indicator applet that shows the price of the BTC using API's from Kraken, BitStamp or BTC-E. It refresh form 3 to every 60 seconds.

I start this applet from the console using make but if I close the console the indicator applet closes too (ofc).

How can I make this indicator applet open from startup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add applets to the top panel in Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/536839/how-do-i-add-applets-to-the-top-panel-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: That question doenst have an answer. And it's not about open indicator applets from startup. So I dont think its a duplicate.

Comment: You asked for: `How can I make this indicator applet open from startup?`. The answer mentions how to do that. :)

Comment: I have tried, and it did not work. When I add the program to be start what is the command I should run? Currently I just go cd to the folder and then enter make.

Comment: When you write a `&` at the end of your terminal command line, the application you start will run in an extra thread that is independent from the terminal. That means you can type more commands or close the terminal after launching the indicator without affecting it.

Comment: I have the answer to my question, I will be more specific. Thanks to all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This indicator applet is opened when you do cd ~/*folder-cloned-from-git*/coinprince-indicator then you use make and the indicator applet opens.

If you want this indicator applet to open from startup you need to do the following:

- Open dash and look for **Startup Applications**
- Open **Startup Applications**
- Click **Add**
- Choose a **name** (coinprice-indicator)
- In command you need to **browse** and choose **coin.py** (~/*folder-cloned-from-git*/coinprince-indicator/coin/coin.py)
- Choose a **comment** (Open coinprice-indicator from Startup)
- Click on **Add**
- **Reboot your system**

Now you will see that the indicator applet opens from startup.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu Miguel, glad to see another from our country.

Comment: Any ideas for this to work on Gnome flashback?  I have to type Make to get it to run, then press ctrl + z and bg to get it in the background. I tried to execute ./coin.py but it does not run.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff, you may want to try with the newer versions

Comment: I just made an account on Coinbase.com and use it as my wallet...Thanks though!